# How to display data from firebase based on result of comparing child items in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to compare or check for all occurrences of the string saved at "place" under "Requests" child which is a string value of location from the Google Maps API.

When I find a match, I would like to display all corresponding values of donationItems in an adapter. I have tried all possible methods I know of but I keep getting unwanted (most times I don't get anything) results.

[Here is a screenshot of my current firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hfo8.png)

Below is the JSON database.

```js
{
  "Users" : {
    "s64OJGXN8UUPQ96Wvw4FnLbNMPt1" : {
      "Donations" : {
        "-LJMEDEyRFjFEyMSb-wD" : {
          "donationCode" : "UULDJFPIGUOE0",
          "donationItems" : "Fries  Nuggets  ",
          "donationQty" : 3,
          "donationplceTxt" : "Calzone's House of Pizza, 1164 W 6th St, Erie, PA 16507, USA"
        },
        "-LJMRPxf3JjjZ5Gu2aNe" : {
          "donationCode" : "JJLFIRIT99EJ",
          "donationItems" : "Burger  Nuggets  ",
          "donationQty" : 2,
          "donationplceTxt" : "Wendy's, 201 E 6th Ave, Denver, CO 80203, USA"
        },
        "-LJMRcaAHU_Jl2pI60TI" : {
          "donationCode" : "804J444JGJ04IJGGGKGIO",
          "donationItems" : "Fries  Burger  ",
          "donationQty" : 4,
          "donationplceTxt" : "Calzone's House of Pizza, 1164 W 6th St, Erie, PA 16507, USA"
        }
      },
      "Requests" : {
        "-LJMGOlrHPMLRMJtVhQ1" : {
          "place" : "Calzone's House of Pizza, 1164 W 6th St, Erie, PA 16507, USA"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code snippet of how I save the location when donating

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            boolean isARestaurant = false;
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            for (int i : place.getPlaceTypes()) {
                if (    i == Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT ||
                        i == Place.TYPE_CAFE
                        ) {
                    isARestaurant = true;
                    StringBuilder stBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String placename = String.format("%s", place.getName());
                    //String latitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                    // String longitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
                    String address = String.format("%s", place.getAddress());
                    stBuilder.append(placename);
                    stBuilder.append(", ");
                    stBuilder.append(address);
                    placeTxt.setText(stBuilder.toString());

                    break;
                }
                if(isARestaurant){
                    //Right type of place
                }else{
                    //Tell to the user to select an appropriate place
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a Restaurant",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// real-time adding to the firebase database
private void SubmitDonation(){

    String donatecode = donateCode.getText().toString();
    String donateitems = "";
    int donateqty = donateQty;
    String donateplceTxt = placeTxt.getText().toString();
    // donateplceTxt = donatePlcTxt;

    for(String Selections : selection){
        donateitems = donateitems + Selections + "  ";
    }

    if((TextUtils.isEmpty(donatecode))){

        Toast.makeText(this, "One or more field(s) missing!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // you can still sprlit these to check for each text field

    }else {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        String id =  UserDonateRef.push().getKey();
        Donation donation = new Donation(donatecode,donateitems,donateqty,donateplceTxt);

        // myRef.child(id).setValue(dessert);
        UserDonateRef
                .child("Users")
                .child(userID)
                .child("Donations")
                .child(id)
                .setValue(donation);

        //Tell to the user to select an appropriate place
        Toast.makeText(this, "The item has been successfully donated!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The code for how I save the request restaurant location is similar.
Below id the code for how I display items on a recyclerview

```
// make these ui items invisible at first instance
    // will make them visible if there are no items to display
    // on recycler view
    noItemsTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    OkExitBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final String curtUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = database.getReference().child("Users");


    // get key id for each instance of donation
    final String donateId =   rootRef.child("All Donations").child(curtUserId).getKey();
    // get key each instance of request
    final String requestId =   rootRef.child("Food Request Restaurant").child(curtUserId).getKey();

    // make a query for all first 50 donation items in All Donations reference
    final Query latestQuery = rootRef
            .child("Donations")
            .child(curtUserId)
            .orderByChild("donationplceTxt")
            .limitToFirst(10);

    // code here to retrieve the string value located at reqRestLoc
    // then compare it with donateRest
    // make another value event listener and get the string?



    latestQuery.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    donationList.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot gigSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Donation donation = gigSnapshot
                                .getValue(Donation.class);


                        donationList.add(donation);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        String donateRest = (String) dataSnapshot
                                .child("All Donations")
                                .child(donateId)
                                .getValue();

                       /* if (s.equals(donateRest)) {   // s = string from reqRestLoc. Does not work
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            noItemsTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            OkExitBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            OkExitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    DisplayItems.super.onBackPressed();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            noItemsTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            OkExitBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }*/
                    }
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You've included a link to a non-existing picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I have included that. Although I am very sure the link to the screenshot of the JSON tree works.

Comment: Imgur links are broken for a lot of folks at the moment (see [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372187/is-i-stack-imgur-com-down) if you want to know more). But images are in general not an ideal way to relay textual information, which is why I often ask for JSON in text form.

Comment: oh, alright. So, how do I go about solving the problem please?